# Djoser Disable Unused Endpoints

Tags: django, djoser

I am using Djoser for authentication in my WebApp and it is pretty fine. However, I'm concerned about some endpoints, like

```
auth/users
```

which returns all users if a token is passed. I won't be using this endpoint and will disable it in frontend as I don't want my users to use it as well. But still, I'm concerned. How can I disable these unused endpoints provided by Djoser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not easily possible to completely disable the endpoints. Maybe restricting this endpoint for admin only will be sufficient?

You could try setting `rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser` permission for `user_list` view.

Something like this should work:

```
DJOSER = {
    'PERMISSIONS': {
        'user_list': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'],
    }
}
```

[DRF IsAdminUser permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser)

[DJoser permissions docs](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#permissions)

Comment: well user list is already allowed only for admin users or it returns info of the current user. Here is a list of all Djoser default settings (as of 23/06/21 line 94 is the permission user_list setting): https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/conf.py#L94

Answer (score 0):

For all future programers.
In order to **disable endpoints** from **djoser** you need to override djoser's **UserViewSet**. Then add your CustomUserViewSet to **urls** and remove **"djoser.urls.base"**.
Now your CustomUserViewSet have all methods from djoser's UserViewSet, but you have control over them, that means you can **override methods** and pass them, or **remove** specyfic http methods from @action.

Here is an example:

Override djoser's **UserViewSet**:

```
from djoser.views import UserViewSet as UVS

# Create your views here.
class CustomUserViewSet(UVS):
```

Add CustomUserViewSet to **urls** and remove "djoser.urls.base":

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("users", views.CustomUserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', include('djoser.urls.base')),
] + router.urls
```

Disable **put** and **patch** from users/me:

```
@action(["get", "delete"], detail=False)
def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.get_object = self.get_instance
    if request.method == "GET":
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```